# Connecting to local fileserver on Fedora 32 fails in Thunar

Tags: linux, fedora, samba

I'm setting up a new install of Fedora 32 and I'm trying to get Samba running so I can access my local file server, which I've had no problems with on my previous ubuntu install.

I've gone through a few Fedora-specific tutorials with no luck, to the end of even installing Samba server, thinking it might cover whatever is making Thunar refuse to connect to the file server.

Once I set up a samba share, 'LOCALHOST' shows up in Thunar, but I get the same error as I do attempting to connect to the file server - specifically, "The specified location is not supported"

Not sure where to go looking for targeted troubleshooting since I'm pretty new to Fedora.  Any suggestions or good links to digest?

Answer (score 0):

Stopped googling a minute too soon.

Turns out Thunar needs a couple extra packages installed to make it work:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624218/thunar-failed-to-open-smb-address-the-specified-location-is-not-supporte